# Moving EKS statefulset pod with PVC to another node

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

My MongoDB is running on EKS node with statefulset of 2 replicas. I wanted to move one of the replicas to another node due to memory limit. I've tried to cordon the target node and delete the pod. However, the new pod is still trying to wait for the original node. I believe this is due to the PVC is still with the original node.

What is the safest way to move one of my MongoDB pods to another node with losing any data?

Comment: Do you have any sort of [mcve] demonstrating the situation; why would the cluster want the Pod to be on a specific node, and how do you create its storage?  Is there a programming-related question or are you just trying to run a database in this environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EKS` is `AWS` manage solution for kubernetes and you need to follow also basic `AWS` concept of storage.

If both of your `MongoDB` replicas where on the same node you probably have 2 storage volumes in the same `availability zone` of region where you are base.
Please note that in `AWS` storage is not shared between `AZ` so if you would like to provision new `EKS` node and `MongoDB` replica should be able to connect to this storage it should be place in the same `AZ` as original node.

Please also make sure that you don't have any `nodeSelector` or `affinity` in your `StatefulSet` manifest that can prevent scheduling new `MongoDB` replica on new node.